# How can I find all documents where a field contains a particular string?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongodb and mongoose and I'm trying to figure out how to do a query that let's me find all records/documents where a field contains a particular string. This is for use with a search feature. For example, if I have a "users" collection, then I want to find all users whose firstname begins with, say, the string "Jo". Like this:

```
var Users = require('./models/users');
Users.find({ firstname : contains the string 'Jo' }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
            return done(err);
    } else {
        return res.json({
            firstname: user.firstname,
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what to put in place of "contains the string 'Jo'" so that this query will work. Basically, it should return records/documents such as "Joe", "John", "Joyce", etc.

**UPDATE===========================================**

Here is the updated code, but it returns all records, instead of only returning the ones that match "str":

```
app.get('/search/:str', function(req, res) {
    var Users = require('./models/users');
    Users.find({name: /[req.params.str]/}, function(err, data) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
});
```

The problem is with `/[req.params.str]/`. If `str` is set to "Jo", then it should only return users whose name contains the string "Jo", but it is returning every record. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can use regular expression for matching. The efficiency is not quite good though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 ways to do this:
With regular expression. MongoDB supports regular expression match. here's an example:

```
users.find({firstname: /Jo/}, function(err, doc) {...})
```

However, if you got a big collection, it's going to be slow. Because regular expression usually doesn't use index at all unless you have a fixed prefix like /^Jo/.

Or in some situations you may want to try the new feature, [full text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/):
First of all, you need an text index:

```
db.users.ensureIndex( { firstname: "text" } );
```

Then use the [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#op._S_text) operator:

```
db.users.find({ $text: { $search: "Jo"}});
```

The text search does not just look for exactly what you are searching. And in some situations it may not work the way you wanted.

> The $text operator can search for words and phrases. The query matches on the complete stemmed words. For example, if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match the document.

More information, please refer to the [document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/).